# Getting an error in intellij referencing a scala method I'm not actually using in a class I have used

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, formatting

I am playing around and learning a bit of scala and have run into a strange error that I don't understand and can't find a way to fix.

Here's the code I'm trying to run:

```
object Classes {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val rover = new Animal()
    rover.setName("Rover")
    rover.setSound("Woof")
    printf("%s says %s\n", rover.getName(), rover.getSound())

    val cat = new Animal("Tiddles", "Meow")
    println(s"${cat.getName()} with ID ${cat.id} says ${cat.getSound()}")

    println(cat.toString())

    val onions = new Dog("Onions", "Woof", "Grrrrrr....")
    onions.setName("Onions")
    println(onions.toString())

    val fang = new Wolf("Fang")
    fang.moveSpeed = 41.56387
    println(fang.move)
}

class Animal (var name: String, var sound: String) {

    this.setName(name)

    val id: Int = Animal.newIdNum

    def getName : String = name
    def getSound: String = sound

    def setName(name : String): Unit = {
        if (!(name.matches(".*\\d+.*")))
            this.name = name
        else
            this.name = "No Name"
    }

    def setSound(sound: String): Unit = {
        this.sound = sound
    }

    def this(name: String) {
        this("No Name", "No Sound")
        this.setName(name)
    }

    def this() {
        this("No Name", "No Name")
    }

    override def toString: String = {
        return "%s with ID %d says %s".format(this.name, this.id, this.sound)
    }
}

object Animal {
    private var idNumber = 0
    private def newIdNum = {
        idNumber += 1;
        idNumber
    }
}

class Dog(name: String, sound: String, growl: String) extends Animal(name, sound) {

    def this(name: String, sound: String) {
        this("No Name", sound, "No Growl")
        this.setName(name)
    }

    def this(name: String) {
        this("No Name", "No Sound", "No Growl")
        this.setName(name)
    }

    def this() {
        this("No Name", "No Sound", "No Growl")
    }

    override def toString: String = {
        return "%s with ID %d says %s or %s\n".format(this.name, this.id, this.sound, this.growl)
    }
}

abstract class Mammal(val name: String) {
    // Just declare variables and only define method signatures
    var moveSpeed : Double
    def move : String
}

class Wolf(name: String) extends Mammal(name) {
    override var moveSpeed: Double = 35.0
    override def move: String = "%s runs at %.2f mph\n".format(this.name, this.moveSpeed)
}
```

}

and here is the error I get:

```
Error:(7, 37) not enough arguments for method apply: (index: Int)Char in class StringOps.
Unspecified value parameter index.
printf("%s says %s", rover.getName(), rover.getSound())

Error:(7, 55) not enough arguments for method apply: (index: Int)Char in class StringOps.
Unspecified value parameter index.
printf("%s says %s", rover.getName(), rover.getSound())

Error:(10, 26) not enough arguments for method apply: (index: Int)Char in class StringOps.
Unspecified value parameter index.
println(s"${cat.getName()} with ID ${cat.id} says ${cat.getSound()}")

Error:(10, 67) not enough arguments for method apply: (index: Int)Char in class StringOps.
Unspecified value parameter index.
println(s"${cat.getName()} with ID ${cat.id} says ${cat.getSound()}")
```

I have not used the apply method from the class StringOps so I have no idea why it is complaining that I have an not specified the parameter; index.

Needless to say, if I comment out the 2 lines mentioned in the errors then it runs.

Any suggestions appreciated as to why the compiler is looking for this apply method.

Comment: You've defined `getName` and `getSound` without parens `()` so you can't add them when invoking these methods. Take them out and it will compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use the companion object to create different variants of a class like this. (I have omitted the `id` and `toString` logic as that is basically OK).

```
class Animal protected (initalName: String, initialSound: String) {
  private def checkedName(name: String): String =
    if (name.matches(".*\\d+.*")) {
      "No Name"
    } else {
      name
    }

  protected var _name = checkedName(initalName)
  def name: String = _name
  def setName(name: String): Unit =
    _name = checkedName(name)

  var sound = initialSound
}

object Animal {
  def apply(name: String, sound: String): Animal = new Animal(name, sound)
  def apply(name: String): Animal = new Animal(name, "No Sound")
  def apply(): Animal = new Animal("NoName", "No Sound")
}

class Dog protected (name: String, sound: String, val growl: String) extends Animal(name, sound)

object Dog {
  def apply(name: String, sound: String, growl: String): Dog = new Dog(name, sound, growl)
  def apply(name: String, sound: String): Dog = new Dog(name, sound, "No Growl")
  def apply(name: String): Dog = new Dog(name, "No Sound", "No Growl")
  def apply(): Dog = new Dog("No Name", "No Sound", "No Growl")
}
```

It is also usual to drop the `get` from accessor methods so that they look like object properties.

Also note that Scala is intended for functional programming so it is typical to make this kind of class immutable. This means that the `setName` method would become a `withName` method and would return a new (immutable) instance of the class. This approach feels more clumsy to start with but reaps benefits as the logic gets more complicated.

Comment: That's really good to know. The way you have defined the constructors using apply actually reads a lot better and makes the code way less verbose. Thanks for the tips :)